# Loading listview icons locally, looking for most efficient process

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-drawable, smooth-scrolling

Im trying to efficiently load my local drawables (from my res>drawable folders) into my list items. I want this to use as little memory as possible while loading my images.

I originally had my resource name (R.drawable.list_icon) defined as an `int` in the model and calling `setImageResource` in my adapter to apply the icon.

However after reviewing the API documentation, it suggests i use `setImageDrawable` or `setImageBitmap` since they are not ran on the UI thread. I need to know if this the following code below, where i've converted the drawable to a bitmap and used `setImageBitmap` is a good method and if loading the local image in a `AsyncTask` is worth incorporating (since i've seen this method used as well).

### Model

```
public class ProductItem {

  public int listIcon;
  public String listTitle;
  public String listDesc;

  public ProductItem(int listIcon, String listTitle,
                   String listDesc) {
    this.listIcon = listIcon;
    this.listTitle = listTitle;
    this.listDesc = listDesc;
 }

 public int getIconID() {
     return listIcon;
 }
}
```

### Adapter

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductItem> {

 Context context;
 int layoutResourceID;
 ProductItem data[];
 ProductHolder viewHolder;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID, ProductItem[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceID, data);
    this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ProductHolder();
        viewHolder.productType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        viewHolder.productDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemSubtitle);
        viewHolder.productImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ProductHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ProductItem objectItem = data[position];

    if (objectItem != null) {
        viewHolder.productType.setText(objectItem.listTitle);
        viewHolder.productType.setTag(objectItem.listTitle);
        viewHolder.productDesc.setText(objectItem.listDesc);
        viewHolder.productDesc.setTag(objectItem.listDesc);
        // Im currently using the following method for obtain the resource. 
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(objectItem.getIconID());
        final Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        viewHolder.productImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        // Im using 'setImageBitmap' since it doesnt run on the UI thread, hoping that this will in return load quicker. 
        // However i was previously using the following.
        // viewHolder.productImage.setImageResource(objectItem.getIconID());

        viewHolder.productImage.setTag(objectItem.listIcon);
    }
    return convertView;
}
static class ProductHolder {
    public TextView productType;
    public TextView productDesc;
    public ImageView productImage;
}
}
```

### Usage

```
listData[0] = new ProductItem(R.drawable.list_icon, getString(R.string.list_title), getString(R.string.list_description));
```

My main question here is what is the most efficient way to load local drawables, These image icon are pretty high quality and not just simple 1 color icons, they are actual product images.

Comment: There are numerous libraries that handle this kind of efficiency.Have you tried Picasso , Glide or UniversalImageLoader?

Comment: I've heard of them, haven't yet tried. This is why i posted the question to gauge how others (who care about efficiently and memory usage) are loading local drawables in listview. I figured most of the libraries really made for loading images from the web and not so much with local drawables. Do you know of one that does this type of optimization for local resources?

Comment: Picasso and Glide can load local images too and handle the efficiency! I have used Picasso and it's pretty neat and fast!

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use UniversalImageLoader. It works well not only for loading images from network.